# What is the significance of algebraic functions in algebraic geometry/number theory?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

I am especially interested in reading Chevalley's 1951 book on the topic. I would like to know how people were led to the study of algebraic functions historically and also the geometrical way to approach the topic which Chevalley mentions in his preface but doesn't elaborate on.

Also it would be nice if someone elaborated on the work done in the Dedekind-Weber paper of 1880.